# Remove redundant SQL price cost records

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a table costhistory with fields id,invid,vendorid,cost,timestamp,chdeleted. It looks like it was populated with a trigger every time a vendor updated their list of prices.

It has redundant records - since it was populated regardless of whether price changed or not since last record.
Example:

```
id | invid | vendorid | cost | timestamp | chdeleted  
1 | 123 | 1 | 100 | 1/1/01 | 0  
2 | 123 | 1 | 100 | 1/2/01 | 0  
3 | 123 | 1 | 100 | 1/3/01 | 0  
4 | 123 | 1 | 500 | 1/4/01 | 0  
5 | 123 | 1 | 500 | 1/5/01 | 0  
6 | 123 | 1 | 100 | 1/6/01 | 0
```

I would want to remove records with ID 2,3,5 since they do not reflect any change since the last price update.

I'm sure it can be done, though it might take several steps.
Just to be clear, this table has swelled to 100gb and contains 600M rows. I am confident that a proper cleanup will take this table's size down by 90% - 95%.

Thanks!

Comment: and... what is your question?

Answer (score 3):

The approach you take will vary depending on the database you are using. For SQL Server 2005+, the following query should give you the records you want to remove:

```
select id 
from (
    select id, Rank() over (Partition BY invid, vendorid, cost order by timestamp) as Rank
    from costhistory 
) tmp
where Rank > 1
```

You can then delete them like this:

```
delete from costhistory 
where id in (
    select id 
    from (
        select id, Rank() over (Partition BY invid, vendorid, cost order by timestamp) as Rank
        from costhistory 
    ) tmp
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you recreate the table using a group by query.  Also, I assume the the "id" column is not used in any other tables.  If that is the case, then you need to fix those tables as well.

Deleting such a large quantity of records is likely to take a long, long time.

The query would look like:

```
insert into newversionoftable(invid, vendorid, cost, timestamp, chdeleted)
    select invid, vendorid, cost, timestamp, chdeleted
    from table
    group by invid, vendorid, cost, timestamp, chdeleted
```

If you do opt for a delete, I would suggestion:

(1) Fix the code first, so no duplicates are going in.
(2) Determine the duplicate ids and place them in a separate table.
(3) Delete in batches.

To find the duplicate ids, use something like:

```
    select *
    from (select id,
                 row_number() over (partition by invid, vendorid, cost, timestamp, chdeleted order by timestamp) as seqnum
          from table
         ) t
    where seqnum > 1
```

If you want to keep the most recent version instead, then use "timestamp desc" in the order by clause.